# Tesseract for Xcode: Library not loaded

Tags: ios, xcode, tesseract

I've been trying to run Tesseract on Xcode by installing the pod via the following file:

`target 'ArchaismDictionaryiOS' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'TesseractOCRiOS'` but whenever I try to launch my app on the iPhone, I get the following error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/TesseractOCR.framework/TesseractOCR
>     Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F0F10977-61CF-4A29-951A-535038EDB921/ArchaismDictionaryiOS.app/ArchaismDictionaryiOS
>     Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>       /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F0F10977-61CF-4A29-951A-535038EDB921/ArchaismDictionaryiOS.app/Frameworks/TesseractOCR.framework/TesseractOCR: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F0F10977-61CF-4A29-951A-535038EDB921/ArchaismDictionaryiOS.app/Frameworks/TesseractOCR.framework/TesseractOCR'
>       /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F0F10977-61CF-4A29-951A-535038EDB921/ArchaismDictionaryiOS.app/Frameworks/TesseractOCR.framework/TesseractOCR: stat() failed with errno=25
>       /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F0F10977-61CF-4A29-951A-535038EDB921/ArchaismDictionaryiOS.app/Frameworks/TesseractOCR.framework/TesseractOCR: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F0F10977-61CF-4A29-951A-535038EDB921/ArchaismDictionaryiOS.app/Frameworks/TesseractOCR.framework/TesseractOCR'
>       /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F0F10977-61CF-4A29-951A-535038EDB921/ArchaismDictionaryiOS.app/Frameworks/TesseractOCR.framework/TesseractOCR: stat() failed with errno=1
>       /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F0F10977-61CF-4A29-951A-535038EDB921/ArchaismDictionaryiOS.app/Frameworks/TesseractOCR.framework/TesseractOCR: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F0F10977-61CF-4A29-951A-535038EDB921/ArchaismDictionaryiOS.app/Frameworks/TesseractOCR.framework/TesseractOCR'
>       /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F0F10977-61CF-4A29-951A-535038EDB921/ArchaismDictionaryiOS.app/Frameworks/TesseractOCR.framework/TesseractOCR: stat() failed with errno=1

I have turned off Bitcode but it doesn't have any effect and changing the framework to use_modular_header in the podfile gives me the error that the project cannot find the Tesseract library. Do you know what the correct way of implementing Tesseract into Xcode and solving this problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an iOS problem. If you update to the newest version of iOS, the problem will be gone and the library will work.